# Client while loop to send and receive from server

Tags: java, networking

This is my client application that is connected to a server. I use an object called DataPackage to send information back and forth. The code runs in its own thread.

The variable `in` is an `ObjectInputStream` and `out` is an `ObjectOutputStream`.

```
DataPackage dp = null;
while (true) {

    try {
        dp = (DataPackage) in.readObject();
        if (dp != null) {
            // Do stuff with received object
        }

        if (sendSomething) { // Send stuff
            out.writeObject( new DataPackage("some data") );
            out.flush();
            out.reset();
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        t.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem with my code is that I never reach the part where I send stuff, unless I receive something from the server. The loop waits for something from the server before it continues to `if (sendSomething)`. How should I structure my code so that I can send stuff any time and receive stuff any time? I hope you understand.

Comment: Would it be possible to create 2 client threads, one for reading, the other for writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the threads. If they use the same socket to communicate with an external server, this is common because they won't block while waiting to read from the socket.

Thread1:

block on read
on recieve message - do something

Thread2:
do things
on something happening - write to socket

Answer (score 1):

The line `dp = (DataPackage) in.readObject();`is blocking. It means that it will not complete execution of lines below until it receives some reply from server.

One advise, create a new thread and pass instance of  `dp = (DataPackage) in.readObject();` so it won't block.